# j Query right side slider panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want create a slider panel, that will be hide and when i click , then it's open and hide , I am trying with this code but not able to get , when i use .hide then .animate function is not working.while using show then div is not slide it's just open form top. but i have in need that slider open form right .

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    body{
      background-color:#FFF;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
      color:#ccc;
      font-size:3em;
      line-height:100px;
      text-align:center;
      overflow:hidden;
    }

    .slider{
      background:#30373f;
      position:absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height:100%;
      top: 0;
      right:0px;
    }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('.slider').hide();
    });
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('.click').click(function(e) {
       $('.slider').animate({right:'100%'}); 
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="click">click for slider</div>
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="text" style="color:#fff; float:right; margin-right:5px; top:10px; z-index:99999; background:#000; position:relative;"><h3><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3></div>   
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you need right side panel with show and hide option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer below code to take an idea. On page load the slider's `right` position is set beyond the visible range and on `click` of label we are setting its `right` position to make it visible.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   
     $('.click').click(function(e) {
       $('.slider').animate({right:'0px'}); 
     });
  
     $('.hideButton').click(function(e) {
       $('.slider').animate({right:'-100%'}); 
     });
 });
```

```css
body{
      background-color:#FFF;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
      color:#ccc;
      font-size:3em;
      line-height:100px;
      text-align:center;
      overflow:hidden;
    }

    .slider{
      background:#30373f;
      position:absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height:100%;
      top: 0;
      right:-100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="click">click for slider</div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="text hideButton" style="color:#fff; float:right; margin-right:5px; top:10px; z-index:99999; background:#000; position:relative;"><h3><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Hide</i></h3></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi vijay can i create a toggle type animation , when i click on hide button i am not able to open again slider panel , i need a toggle type animation can you help me you there

Comment: Hello Sanjay. Where you will be putting hide button. Could you please update HTML so that i can take a look at that? Will that be on panel that is coming from right?

Comment: yeh it's ok , but issues is here when panel is hide and again try to open , it;s does not open without refreshing the browser,

Comment: try to put alert in both `.click` function. See if u get the alert.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114116/discussion-between-sanjay-yadav-and-vijayp).

Comment: you there? i am facing css issues , ho can i hide right side, when i do -100% the dive slide -100% and here a big issues with responsive

Answer (score 1):

animate({right ... makes the slider's property right to change, whereas hide() hides it completely. So even if you change the 'right' property, your slider is still hidden. You either have to remove hide() and just move your slider offscreen with css (the best option imo), or remove animate() and just use show(), but for sliding animation you have to go with the first option.

Answer (score 1):

The problem your having is that .hide() is adding the "display:none" style to the .slider div you aren't then removing this before animating using something like .show().

It might be a better idea instead of hiding the div to make it have 0 width.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only 1 document.ready function in your page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.slider').hide();
    $('.click').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

       var slider = $('.slider');

       if(slider.css('display') == "none"){
          $('.slider').animate({right:'0'}); 
       }else{
          $('.slider').animate({right:'-100%'}); 
      }
   });  
});
```

By default the slider should be display none, and right value should be -ve.